# Calling derived class method from generic base class reference

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a base class

```
class base {
  public:
    base();
    int someData;
    virtual void foo(){
      std::cout << someData;
    }
};
```

and a few derived classes like

```
class derived : public base {
  public:
    derived();
    void foo(){
     std::cout << someData * 5;
  }
};
```

Basically they have the same kind of data but the operations on this data are different.
I have another class that doesn't need to know the details of my object, all it needs to do is to set data and call the derived foo().

```
class useData {
  public:
    useData();

    base x;
    int do() { x.someData = 5; return x.foo(); }
};
```

I want "useData" to be as generic as possible so I'm using the base class instead of the derived class in its definition. 
Of course in this scenario it will call the base method and not the derived one. How can I rewrite my code or make it automatically (without type checking or similar) call the derived method?

Thank you

Comment: Store a reference or a pointer to `base`. `base x;` will always be a `base` only, never `derived`.

Comment: Please see my answer to Hivert.
There must be something I forgot because I know this is how polymorphism is meant to work but right now I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Then show your real code.

Comment: can you use overloading to detect the type you want based on the type of argument passed?

Answer (score 1):

To use polymorphism you need some pointer or references. So in `useData` the variable `x` should be declared as a `base *`. Afterward, you can create is using a `new` with any derived class. Polymorphism will perform as expected..

Comment: I know I have to use a pointer (sorry, the code I wrote was a very basic stub) but maybe I'm missing something else.
If I do "new derived()" it means I know what kind of derived class to use so my useData class is not generic and need to have knowledge about every kind of derived class. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You appear to misunderstand polymorphism. You typically need to know what type of object you are instantiating (there are exceptions). Once you have a pointer to the instantiated object, it does not matter what it's derived class is if you wish to perform base operations.

Comment: @Codeluppi So let's assume you have also derived `derived2` from `base`. Then how the compiler should now which `foo()` implementation to use?